# How to set specific gpu in bert?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model

**ResourceExhaustedError** (see above for traceback):

> OOM when allocating tensor of shape [768] and type float   [[node
>   bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta/adam_m/Initializer/zeros
>   (defined at /home/zyl/souhu/bert/optimization.py:122)  =
>   Const_class=["loc:@bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta/adam_m/Assign"],
>   dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

How to set **gpu** 1 or another to run **bert**?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to set what GPUs will be used is setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable. It will still be `GPU:0` TensorFlow, different physically different device.

If you are using BERT within Python (which is rather a painful way), you can use the code that is creating BERT graph in a block:

```py
with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
   model = modeling.BertModel(...)
```